# Pass Firebase document ID on tapping UITableView cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, segue

I followed this solution and I was able to get it to work successfully:

[how to get document id on tapping the uitablecellviewcell in Firestore in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722835/how-to-get-document-id-on-tapping-the-uitablecellviewcell-in-firestore-in-swift)

However, now my challenge is how do I pass the documentID to the next view controller on Segue? I understand I have to use the following function:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

Also how do I call the documentID in the next view controller?

I would truly appreciate any advice you may be able to provide. Thank you!

Comment: If you show just one line of code in seeking help, you are not helping yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data through segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard segues, then in the function you can write

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let detailVC = segue.destination as? UIViewControllerDetail else{
        return
    }
    detailVC.documentID = documentID
}
```

Where UIViewControllerDetail is the viewcontroller class that gets presented when the user taps on the cell.
In the UIViewController detail, make sure to add the documentID property

```
var documentID: String?
```